# Symfony2 best practice for complex forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, handle

I have a complex database schema in my Symfony2 application, with a lot of entities linked to each others.

Consequently, my forms are also complicated : I can have many linked forms ; for example a "Cinema" can have an Address, but can also be linked to several "Movies" (with a button to add a new movie).

It's very very difficult to handle this using basic Symfony2 form Types ; **I prefer to create my own form manually in a Twig view** ; using a bunch of Javascript.

But I don't know how to handle the form submission ?

- Should I define a CinemaType and use it only to handle the form request (but not for creating the form view) ?
- Should I use a `createFormBuilder()` in my Controller to define the basic form fields and check them with the `handleRequest()` method ?
- Or, finally, should **get all my _POST data and check them manually** ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at form collections? http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.  Not seeing anything in your problem description that looks difficult.  I agree that twig can get in the way.  I implemented my own form twig extension to get more control of the html output.  But the forms do a good job of mapping between an aggregate root object and html form elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand very well the problem...

---

**You can play with your multiple nested form** and the whole structure (html + js) is in the doc:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

The official doc gives too a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/847Kf/4/

Just an extract for the answer validation :

```
function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

    // Replace '$$name$$' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);

    // also add a remove button, just for this example
    $newFormLi.append('<a href="#" class="remove-tag">x</a>');

    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

    // handle the removal, just for this example
    $('.remove-tag').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().remove();

        return false;
    });
}
```

---

**You can customize the rendering**, or/and creating your own theme :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

---

**You can handle the form validation** :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

---

And if you are good at ergonomics, you can create pretty form splited in multiple tabs or with any other thinkable design...

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own simple form class that implements the same methods as the Symfony2 ones:

- handleRequest
- validate
- createView

And so on.

Comment: Isn't `bind` droped in favor of `handleRequest`? In the new versions (2.7 and 2.8 branches) I don't see `bind` anymore.

Comment: True, was looking on an old project.